# Django application seems to use old QuerySet results for new requests based on date.today() filtering

Tags: django, caching, django-queryset, tastypie

I've a Django application served by uWSGI processes on an nginx server. This application uses tastypie for API management and memcached to cache some template blocks.

**My problem is that API requests keep returning old results.**

I'm filtering my query by date

```
queryset = Event.objects.filter(status='P').exclude(date_end__lt=date.today()).order_by('-featured', 'date_end')
```

but the returned objects are the same every day.

I also added `date.today` to the context for debugging purpose and it correctly outputs the current date.

**When I restart uWSGI processes the QuerySet is evaluated correctly.**

So I exclude DB and memcached from this problem. To me it seems like some sort of QuerySet caching is being done by tastypie or uWSGI processes.

I've read [tastypie caching documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/caching.html) and tried the NoCache class with no success.

I've also read [Django doc about QuerySet caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) but aren't QuerySet objects supposed to be thrown away after each request?

**UPDATE**

I checked response headers and client cache expires after 60 seconds with a max-age of an hour.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2013 10:47:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Feb 2013 10:44:56 GMT
Expires: Mon, 18 Feb 2013 10:54:56 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my query as suggested

```
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(status='P').exclude(date_end__lt=date.today).order_by('-featured', 'date_end')
```

but the result is still the same.

Here is a JSON output example

```
{
    "date_begin": "11/17/2012",
    "date_end": "11/17/2012",
    "description": "Presentazione del libro di Daniela Giusto",
    "featured": false,
    "location": "Libreria antiquaria Romeo Prampolini",
    "resource_uri": "/api/v1/event/213/",
    "time": "18:00:00",
    "title": "Un insolito Jules Verne. Tradurre umorismo e fantasia",
    "today": "2012-11-18",
}
```

`date_begin` and `date_end` are formatted in a different way for javascript compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your QuerySet object is not request-scoped in Tastypie; it persists across requests.  Thus your date.today is only evaluated once (even if you pass the date.today function as an argument instead of its return value), and not per request like you expect.  Check out [this recipe](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset) from the Tastypie docs for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your queryset value:

```
queryset = Event.objects.filter(status='P').exclude(date_end__lt=date.today)
```

Comment: To explain: the `date.today()` means it is called when the class is first imported (on process startup). Leaving it as `date.today` means Django knows to call it on evaluation.

Comment: so `events` queryset is working because `timedelta` has a parameter?